# How to extract text from specific columns from a csv file in c#?

Tags: c#

I have been working on extracting text from a csv file and store the data in a string. But now, I would like to extract text from some of the specific columns  and store the data in a string.I would like the `wordDocContents` variable to contain the specific columns and the data in those specific columns  which is `bank_account`, `bank_name`, `customer_name`. Currently, my `wordDocContents` has the entire data from my csv file. Is there a way to filter out the specific columns and the data in those columns and store it in the variable `wordDocContents`. Thanks

Here is what I tried so far -

```
public void button1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    button1.Text = "You clicked me";

    var textExtractor = new TextExtractor();

    var wordDocContents = textExtractor.Extract("t.csv");
    Console.WriteLine(wordDocContents);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for class to parse structured files.

Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx for details.